# How do you use javascript to set a variable to a link?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a website that has a course in HTML. Every lesson/page on the website will have the same format because I was trying to set a link in a button to a variable surrounded in quotes. Ex. 
`"document.getElementById("completedLessons").innerHTML = "<a href=\"lesson" + lessonsCompleted + ".html"`, then I would set lessonsCompleted to the amount of lessons completed. Then I put the button at the bottom of my code: `<p id="completedLessons"></p><button>Start</button></a>`. My computer has Chrome OS and doesn't have Linux, so it can't run python, PHP, etc.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the closing double quote on the `href` attribute. The `".html"` should be `".html\""`. (This would be a lot easier to write using template literals.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<a id='lessonAnchor' href='not a thing yet'>Lesson Anchor<a>
<script>
   document.getElementById('lessonAnchor').href=
      "lesson" + lessonsCompleted + ".html";
</script>
```